# Facebook sdk framework not found ios7, xcode5

Tags: objective-c, ios7, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am new to Facebook SDK with iOS. I want to send invitation to friends on Facebook for using my app for this I am using Facebook (developer.facebook.com)sdk api I have registered my app installed sdk and imported framework. After importing got error as,

```
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-  
 F/Users/vijaywebsolutions/Documents/FacebookSDK'
 ld: framework not found FacebookSDKkk
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you try **CocoaPods** for your projects its the dependency manager for Objective-C projects.

Refer [**CocoaPods**](http://beta.cocoapods.org/)

Simple Setup

- Open Terminal and type **sudo gem install cocoapods**

Once installed you need to create a simple Pod file in your project directory and add the dependency to that file example.

Go to your project root directory and create Pod File by typing in terminal **touch Podfile**

Once created add the following line to the podfile.

```
platform :ios
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK',       '~> 3.11.0'
```

Save the file and then in the terminal(where pod file exist) run **pod install**

Now it will install the requested dependencies and will create a Workspace for your project, you don't need to take any effort to configure it.

**Its the best way to manage your dependencies. Give it a try you won't regret.**

Comment: @user3146268 Did you try cocoapods?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to include facebook sdk in you project, steps as follows :

1. click on your project folder in xcode.
2. go to general tab and find **Linked framework and libraries**.
3. in that click on **+** sign and provide path to `FacebookSDK.framework`

These steps will facebook sdk in your project.

Then you have to import it in any of `.m` file where you want to use is it. like following line :

`#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`

Comment: can you see `FacebookSDK.framework` in Frameworks folder of your project?

Comment: try to add that line in your header file, which is `.h`

Comment: if `FacebookSDK.framework` is there in Frameworks folder of your project, then this is all what you have to do. Otherwise it may be problem of framework integration. It would be better if you also copy SDK in your project folder.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into similar error when integrating FacebookSDK into my app. I have added the framework in the **Link Binary with Libraries**, however, error persisted. One important thing to note when app is built, is it should be build against **source** Facebook iOS SDK and NOT **binary** SDK. I got latest source from here [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), downloaded Bolts-iOS and XCTOOL and then ran **build_framework.sh** Once completed, copied **FacebookSDK.framework** to my app and everything worked perfect.